# is.element() doesn't check correctly (?) in R

Tags: r

I got a little weird problem here:

```
setProgress <- function(total) {
    ticks <- seq(.01, 1, by = 0.01) * total
    return(ticks)
}

ticks <- setProgress(10000)
is.element(100, ticks)
is.element(205, ticks)
# ...
is.element(700, ticks)
```

If you run that code you will get:

Clearly 100 is part of the vector `ticks`. -> `TRUE` 
205 is obviously not. -> `FALSE`
700 **is** part of `ticks`but I receive the output `FALSE`.

What is going on here?

Cheers,
Martin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a rounding error.  Set `options(digits=22)` and view `ticks`.  You'll find this value:  `7000.0000000000009094947`

The error is because `0.7` cannot be exactly represented as a binary floating point number.

You may be able to fix it by using this definition:

```
 setProgress <- function(total) { seq(total/100, total, length=100) }
```